# Bayes Nash equilibrium distribution

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, bayesian-game

I would like to define a decision rule that is induced by a BNE distribution in a game with a continuum of agents.

For that, I have a decision rule $\varphi:\Theta \rightarrow\Delta(\Delta(A))$ that prescribes an average (or the most likely) action at each realised state of the world. The logic is that when an agent is privately recommended action $a_i$ by the omniscient mediator, the agent can expect which recommendation others will have on average.

Now, given an action type state distribution $\pi∈Δ(Δ(A×T)×Θ)$, I want to formally express the fact that: (i) $\pi$ is induced by a BNE, and (ii) $\varphi$ is induced by $\pi$.

I know for (ii), that   $\varphi$ = marg$_{(Δ(A)×Θ)} π$ but I cannot express it since I don't know how to formally write condition (I).

My guess for (I) would be as follows:

Let $z∈Δ(A×T)$ be the distribution of realised actions and states. $\delta_Θ∈Δ(Θ)$ and $\delta_T∈Δ(T)$ are the common priors on states and types respectively.

Let $\beta$ be a BNE where $\beta=∏_{i∈I}\beta_i(a_i|t_i)$.

Suppose that all BNE are collected in $B$ such that $b∈Δ(B)$ is a distribution on the space of BN equilibria.
Thus, a BNE induces $\pi$ if:

$\pi(z,θ)$ = $\delta_Θ(θ)$$\delta_T(t|θ)$$b(\beta|t)$

(I am not sure about that as one distribution seems to be redundant)

Therefore, $\pi$ induces $\varphi$ provided that

$\varphi$ = $∫_T$$\delta_Θ(θ)$$\delta_T(t|θ)$$b(\beta|t)$

????!!!!?????

It does not make sense to me. I would appreciate if anyone could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you define the game and the terminology used first.

Comment: Hello Michael. Thanks for helping... I'm tying to adapt the Bergemann and Morris (2016) paper to a setup with a continuum of agents. I know that they already did it in an early working paper, but I am trying to simplify the framework to use it in a Keynesian beauty contest. In their 2013 paper, they skipped the part where the BCE is induced by the BNE distribution, so I'm working on that.

The thing with continuum of agents is that decision rules are distributions on distribution of actions (rather than distribution on the space of action). That's why I am struggling...

Comment: Why is a decision rule a function to distributions over distributions over actions? How are type spaces defined? BNE?